# How to extract value from json response in postman, whose key has '.' in it

Tags: json, response, postman

It is pretty straight forward to to get a value of a key from json response in postman say :

```
pm.test("AddCluster", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    pm.globals.set("taskIdCluster", jsonData.value);    
});
```

For JSON Response

```
{
    "value": "task-1405"
}
```

I am not able to extract json value in the below case where key has a '.' as part of its string.Can any one help me with this.

```
"result": {
        "cluster.moid": "domain-c433242"
    }
```

I tried the following below code:

```
pm.test("abc", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    var result = jsonData.result;
    var moid = result.'cluster.moid' ;
    pm.environment.set("clusterMoid", moid);
});
```

Comment: have you tried var moid = result.'cluster.moid' ?

Comment: Thanks Joly it worked!

Comment: wonderful ! I suggest you edit and upgrade your answer so all the community can benefit from it, thanks !

Comment: @A.Joly : :) :)

Answer (score 1):

Could figure out to extract value for the above case, The below code works

```
pm.test("StatusForAddClusterApplyCheck", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    var result = jsonData.result;
    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(result).substring(17,31);
    pm.environment.set("clusterMoid", jsonString);
});
```

But only if the string length are constants.

Any other answer in case string length are dynamic?

Answer (score 1):

In javascript (And also in postman), object properties can be accessed with '.' operator or with associative array indexing using []. The same goes for JSON objects.

ie. **object.key** is equivalent to **object["key"]**.

this should do the trick for you:

```
pm.test("AddCluster", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    pm.globals.set("taskIdCluster", jsonData["cluster.moid"]);
});
```